# nvidia settings multi screen problem ( can't save settings, need to redo it every session )

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, multiple-monitors, nvidia-settings

I have a problem with multi-screen problem and Nvidia settings on 22.04, I recently plugged in a 3rd screen and needed to adjust its position through Nvidia settings, but somehow this application restore default settings every time I restart.
I already changed the permission to allow it to modify the conf file when hitting save to X configuration file, but still, every time I close it after modification and hit Apply then save to conf file, it says I did not apply it and does not keep it after reboot.

Would someone happen to know why?

Here are the captures of the problem (it says I didn't hit apply, where I did it, and it greyed out once you did it ) :

[image: nvidia settings capture]

[image: nvidia settings capture]

[image: nvidia settings capture]